# How to use a model in a Python Django project for multiple applications?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project called myoffice. In this project I created an app proposals. Before creating this I had performed makemigrations and migrate creating auth_user table and other tables like auth_user_groups etc.

After creating proposals app, it was working fine.

Now I created a new app called expenses. I have written all models, views, templates and url files. In my models, a couple of models have foreign key reference to users like this:

```
exch_usr = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I have imported user model as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Yet, I am getting an error while running makemigrations:

```
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'txn_usr' yet, because its related model 'User' has not been loaded yet
```

Comment: What I want to do is that every transaction will have a field which will be foreign key reference to user table.

Answer (score 1):

If the linked model is in another app, you need to refer to that in the destination string.

```
exch_usr = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Note, you do not need to import User at all.

Comment: I called it as `exch_usr = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

Now I get an error - `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (exch_usr) specified for Exchange`

Answer (score 0):

If you are already importing User model on that models.py, you can just set it to ForeignKey. be aware that it's not a string.

```
exch_usr = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The @danielr 's answer is perfect but I have a recommendation for you @Parry. So if the User model might be swapped out for another(thinking in the future) and to make your application as reusable as possible you should use the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as a references in your models . More information on customizing and referencing the User model can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model. And inside your code you must use the get_user_model Django(to create User references ) utility to create this switch in a clean way.

`class SomeClass(models.Model):
    ....
    custome_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

and to make references to User properties:

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
 User = get_user_model()
 class AnotherClass(models.Model):
    ....
    username = User.USERNAME_FIELD`

Comment: I tried your solution but it was giving me error - `models are not loaded yet`. So I tried adding following to models.py

`import Django`
`django.setup()`

but now it just hangs on makemigrations.

Comment: @Parry : I have no clear what you have in models.py. show me more please.
Notwithstanding you must do what I recommend you in the first makemigrations because do it after the first makemigrations can run in troubles so if you have a already started project do not do it read this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project